# why can not find a user with that e-mail address?

Tags: laravel

```php
public function create(Request $request) { 
    $this->validate($request, [ 'email' => 'required|email', ]);
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user) 
        return response()->json([
           'message' => 'We can not find a user with that e-mail address.' 
        ], 404);
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? This would return a 404 if it could find the user since you have `if ($user)` meaning if user is a truthy (in this case non-null) value

Comment: `if ($user) {  -- this is missing --  }` curly bracket missing on your `if statement`

Comment: see the working solution below. Tested on my app.

Comment: @TalhaF. apparently that's not the problem. It will work without the brackets as well. You can test it if you need clarifications. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this.

This will return a `success` with user found if user is actually in DB with email or `return` `404` with NO user found.

```
public function create(Request $request) { 
    $this->validate($request, [ 'email' => 'required|email', ]);
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User Found'
         ], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'We can not find a user with that e-mail address.' 
         ], 404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use the `exists` method of validation

```
public function create(Request $request) { 

       $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:user,email',
       ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `isEmpty()`,  Like this :

```
public function create(Request $request) { 
    
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user->isEmpty())  {
        return response()->json([
             'message' => 'We can not find a user with that e-mail address.' 
        ], 404);
     } else {
          return response()->json([
             'message' => 'User is found'], 201 );
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. Are you sure with and have tested this before answering here. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you have tested this `isEmpty` function ? you will be able to see the error message. Its ideal to use straight `if ($user)` straight. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping,  yes I checked & its working fine. 
    https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
public function create(Request $request) { 
    $this->validate($request, [ 'email' => 'required|email', ]);
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'We can not find a user with that e-mail address.' 
        ], 404);
    }
}
```